# iPhone on silent except for calls

Tags: notifications, alert

When I sleep, I don't want to hear any notifications from my phone, unless I get a phone call. In case it's an emergency from a family member, etc.

Is there a way to set it to silent on every app but phone calls easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the contacts you want to allow to call you when you are sleeping to a group an give that group a name.
Then: Settings > Do not Disturb > Allow Calls From > select group of contacts that you created.

Additionally you may select to allow repeated calls (if someone will call you second time within 3 minutes - you will hear it) and choose Scheduled if you want to schedule your Do Not Disturb to switch on automatically.